# Using jquery/js in partial view MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a partial view that I call with an `@Ajax.BeginForm` and then put it in a `div` inside my original view.

Well, the problem is that I have some jquery libraries that I really need to use inside my partial view and they don't work at all. I've tried making a new partial view with all scripts/css links and tried `@Html.Partial("_ScriptLinkView")`, but that didn't work.

Searched for some answers and found some that I tried but it still didn't work. Anyone knows how to do this?

_Layoutview:

```
<!DOCTYPE Html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<link href="../../Content/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../Content/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../Content/samples.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript">    </script>
<script src="../../Scripts/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/date.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-calx-1.1.9.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
            <!-- Header -->
            <div id="header">
                <img id="calcfactorylogo" src="../../Images/CalcFactory.png" alt="Calcfactory logo" />
            </div>
            <div id="body">
                    @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
                <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
                    @RenderBody()
                </section>
            </div>
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
            @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
            <div id="footer">           
                <img id="telloxlogo" src="../../Images/telloxlogo.png">
            </div>      
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My main view:

```
@model CalcFactory.Models.Calculation
<!-- Container for whole page -->
<div id="container">
            <!-- Menu nav -->
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="navbar">    
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                          <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                          <li class="active">@Html.ActionLink("Create Calculation", "CreateCalculation", "Home")</li>
                          <li>@Html.ActionLink("Compare Calculation", "CompareCalculation", "Home")</li>
                          <li>@Html.ActionLink("Get Calculation", "GetCalculation", "Home")</li>
                        </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- Content -->
            <div class="content">

                <!-- Menu buttons for annuity and amortization -->
                <div id="createCalcMenu">
                    @Ajax.ActionLink("Annuity", "Annuity", "Calculation", new AjaxOptions
                    {
                        UpdateTargetId = "calcDiv",
                        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                        HttpMethod = "POST"
                    })
                    <br />              
                    @Ajax.ActionLink("Amortization", "Amortization", "Calculation", new AjaxOptions
                    {
                        UpdateTargetId = "calcDiv",
                        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                        HttpMethod = "POST"
                    })
                </div>

                <div id="calcDiv"></div>
```

And my partialview:

```
<div id="annuityCalc">
                    <legend id="legendWidth"><h1>Annuity calculation
                        <div class="row" id="saveAndPrintImage">
                            <a href="#" title="Save"><img src="../../Images/glyphicons_446_floppy_save.png" alt="save"></a>
                            <a href="#"><img title="Print" src="../../Images/glyphicons_015_print.png" alt="print"></a>
                        </div>
                            </h1>
                    </legend>
                    <!-- Contains forms and input for annuity calculation -->
                    <div class="calcInput" id="calcInput">
                    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("ShowDetail", "Calculation", new AjaxOptions
                    {
                        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                        UpdateTargetId = "anCalcDetail",
                        LoadingElementId = "Loader"
                    }))
                    {
                       //Form here
                    }
                    </div>
                    <form id="itemlist">
  Item  : <input type="text" id="A1" value="HDD Baracuda Black 2TB" /><br>
  Price : <input type="text" id="B1" data-format="$ 0,0[.]00" /><br>
  Qty   : <input type="text" id="C1" data-format="0" /><br>
  Disc. : <input type="text" id="D1" data-format="0[.]00 %" /><br>
  Total : <input type="text" id="E1" data-formula="($B1*$C1)*(1-$D1)" /><br>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#itemlist').calx();
</script>

                    <div class="calcGraph">
                    </div>
                    <div class="calcDetail" id="anCalcDetail">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

The last form (itemlist) in my partialview is taken from http://www.xsanisty.com/project/calx/. That is the library I wanna use in my partialview. If I post the same example in my main view it works perfectly fine. But in my Partialview it don't.

Comment: Have you tried putting script references in the main View, so that they are available to the partial?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that, didn't work wither.

Comment: Do you have scripts section in your layout?

Comment: Yes, in my _Layout.cshtml (works like my masterpage or something) I have script tags inside <head> tags

Comment: Post the code for your main view and your partial view.

Comment: did you try wrapping `$('#itemlist').calx();` in document ready?

Comment: @scniro yes. When I look in Developer Tools I get this: http://cdn.imghack.se/images/6d3f955e500cf85ea55357746e215a50.png, so it seems that the calx library can't be declared properly..But when even if I declare all scripts in main view it doesn't work either

Comment: How many forms do you have in your partial view? Your Ajax form shouldn't work. The form elements should be inside `@using(Ajax.BeginForm()...`.

Comment: @ataravati I have one form like I described in the code, and it's working. Can try your way but is it possible that it's making problem with link to my jquery calx?

Comment: I see three forms in your code. There's an Ajax form, a from with the id = "itemlist", and then there's a comment for another form (// Form here) right after the Ajax form.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar w/ calx but my guess would be that there is some initialization in jquery-calx-1.1.9.js that runs when the document loads, so it may be that you need to move it to a script tag at the end of the body...hence @Ufuk's question about a scripts section, which allows pages to inject script to the end of the doc body, after all the dom is there...

```
        @RenderSection("scripts", false)
</body>
</html>
```

You could putting the script ref there to verify this:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-calx-1.1.9.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```